# CanvasContext2D drawImage() issue [onload and CORS]

Tags: javascript, canvas, html5-canvas

I am trying to paint an image on a canvas before I get its `dataURL()`, but the data returned is like empty.

When I check it in the console, I see there is a lot of `A` in the string : (`"data:image/png;base64,iVBO..some random chars... bQhfoAAAAAAAAAA... a lot of A ...AAAASUVORK5CYII="`)

When I try to append the canvas to the document, nothing is drawn either and I don't have any error thrown in the console.

What is the problem here ?

Here is my code :

```
var img = new Image();
img.src = "http://somerandomWebsite/picture.png";
var canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
canvas.width = img.width;
canvas.height = img.height;
var context = canvas.getContext('2d');
context.drawImage(img, 0,0); // this doesn't seem to work
var dataURL = canvas.toDataURL(); // this will give me a lot of "A"    
doSomething(dataURL);
```

Also, when doing a quick refresh, the image gets drawn correctly onto the canvas but I've got an error message in the console and `dataURL` is empty.

The message in Firefox is : *"SecurityError: The operation is insecure."*,
in Chrome it is *"Uncaught SecurityError: Failed to execute 'toDataURL' on 'HTMLCanvasElement': Tainted canvases may not be exported."*,
and on IE I just get *"SecurityError"*.

What does it mean ?

Comment: This post is meant to be a canonical one for the 20 or so a week we get about this particular issue. Please let me know if it can be improved.

Comment: Isn't just the point of loading images before doing anything with them more relevant ? And if you think useful to refer to toDataURL, you should mention the (possible) CORS issue. Anyway +1 for the wiki idea / effort.

Comment: @GameAlchemist you're right, I tried to combine both issues, since they're really similar and often come in pair. I talked about the CORS issue in the answer. Don't know how search engines will deal with that though, maybe I should add the "canvas is tainted" message error into the question. Anyway, I asked that the question is converted to wiki too, this way, you'll be able to edit it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You have to wait that your image has **loaded** before you can paint it on the canvas.

To do so, simply use the `load` event handler of your `<img>` element :

```
// create a new image
var img = new Image();
// declare a function to call once the image has loaded
img.onload = function(){
  var canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
  canvas.width = img.width;
  canvas.height = img.height;
  var context = canvas.getContext('2d');
  context.drawImage(img, 0,0);
  var dataURL = canvas.toDataURL();
  // now you can do something with the dataURL
  doSomething(dataURL);
}
// now set the image's src
img.src = "http://somerandomWebsite/picture.png";
```

Also, for the canvas' `context.toDataURL()` and `context.getImageData` to work properly, you have to get your image resource in a [cross-origin compliant way](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/CORS_enabled_image), otherwise the canvas is "tainted" which means that any method to get pixels data will be blocked.

- If your image comes from the same **server**, no problem.
- If your image is served from an **external server**, be sure that it allows yours in its cross-origin headers and set the `img.crossOrigin` to `"use-credentials"`.
- If the **server** does allow anonymous requests, you can set the `img.crossOrigin` to `"anonymous"`.

*Nota Bene* : [CORS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS) **header is sent by the server**, the `cross-origin` attribute will only let it know that you want to use CORS to get the image data, in no way you can circumvent it if **the server** is not set properly.
Also some UserAgents (IE & Safari) still haven't implemented this attribute.

*Edge Case* : If some of your images are from your server and some are from a CORS compliant one, then you may want to use the `onerror` event handler which should fire if you set the `cross-origin` attribute to `"anonymous"` on a non CORS server.

```
function corsError(){
  this.crossOrigin='';
  this.src='';
  this.removeEventListener('error', corsError, false);
} 
img.addEventListener('error', corsError, false);
```