# How to add text to image canvas?

Tags: javascript, canvas

I try to add text to image, but I fail. Anyone can help me. 
thanks!

```
function myCanvas() {
  var c = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
  var ctx = c.getContext("2d");
  var img = document.getElementById("Tshirtsrc");
  ctx.drawImage(img, 3, 3, 350, 350);
  ctx.fillStyle = "red";
  ctx.font = "18px sans-serif";
  ctx.fillText("This is a test", 50, 400);
}
```

Comment: Can we have a code snippet or a jsfiddle?

Comment: When are you calling this code? [maybe related](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32880641/canvascontext2d-drawimage-issue-onload-and-cors). Also, what is the type of `#Tshirtsrc` element ?

Comment: jsFiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/9f73ha2n/1/ works fine for me

Comment: @Canvas, but this is not OP's code...

Comment: @Kaiido I can only work with what the OP has given. The only difference my code has is I create a new image instead of use an `img` tag. I can change that but I don't think that is the issue. Binh have you tried looking at your console to see if you have any errors?

Comment: @Canvas, no, the main difference between your code and OP's one is that you do use the `onload` event. Also, your `img` variable is actually referring to an ImageElement, which we can't be sure it is in OP's code.

Comment: @Canvas tks! I have solved it !

Comment: Then why not share the solution...

Comment: @Shikkediel or close the question...

Comment: Good point, let me follow my new "duty" in that respect.