# Javascript canvas drawImage is not working, and it is throwing no error

Tags: javascript, canvas

Here is a very straightforward bit of code I made, that just isn't working! It is throwing no errors.

```
window.onload = function() {
    var canvas = document.getElementById("paper");

    var bob = canvas.getContext("2d");
    var background = canvas.getContext("2d");

    background.fillStyle = "rgb(0, 0, 0)"
    background.fillRect(0, 0, 400, 400);

    var bobImg = new Image();
    bobImg.src = "Drawing (1).png";

    bob.drawImage(bobImg, 35, 35, 400, 400);
}
```

It should be working, and I am having a similar prob with other programs I made. It is just showing the black background, but not the image. Thank you guys for any help! =D

Comment: What does "not working" mean?  Are you not seeing anything?  Are some things showing up and others not?  Also, you have not included the relevant HTML as that is a potential part of the problem.

Comment: Ill change it so that it is more clear. Thanks.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [CanvasContext2D drawImage() issue \[onload and CORS\]](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32880641/canvascontext2d-drawimage-issue-onload-and-cors)

Answer (score 1):

You need to wait for the image to load before you can draw it. To do that add an event handler for the image load event and put your draw code there. For example:

```
window.onload = function() {
    var canvas = document.getElementById("paper");

    var bob = canvas.getContext("2d");
    var background = canvas.getContext("2d");

    background.fillStyle = "rgb(0, 0, 0)"
    background.fillRect(0, 0, 400, 400);

    var bobImg = new Image();
    bobImg.addEventListener("load", function() {
        bob.drawImage(bobImg, 35, 35, 400, 400);
    }, false);
    bobImg.src = "Drawing (1).png";

}
```

Comment: No problem - fell over that myself in the past :)