# How to get FileType from a DOM with JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, image, download, file-type

Here is a DOM like this.

`<img id="this-is-the-image" src="http://192.168.1.100/Image_tmp/2016-06/d4eb8d">`

I need to click a button, run a JS, and download this image file.

I have finished the button and the download script.

Some code:

```

```
function downloadFile(fileName, url) {
        var aLink = document.createElement('a');
        var blob = new Blob([url]);
        var evt = document.createEvent("HTMLEvents");
        getImageType(blob);
        evt.initEvent("click", false, false);
        aLink.download = fileName;
        aLink.href = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
        aLink.dispatchEvent(evt);
    }
```

```

I have a problem. I can only get the src `"http://192.168.1.100/Image_tmp/2016-06/d4eb8d"` or the name `d4eb8d`, but actually the image is `.png` or `.jpg`.
The brower can view it, but after I `save` it to my computer, the file name turn to be `d4eb8d`, not `d4eb8d.png` or `d4eb8d.jgp`.
How can I get the real type of the image so that I can specify the download_name?

Comment: It seems, this script get the url-string data instead of img-data. I think FileReader can only read file from local.

Comment: _"It seems, this script get the url-string data instead of img-data. I think FileReader can only read file from local."_ Was curious what purpose of `new Blob([url])` was? You can use `XMLHttpRequest()` to retrieve image as `Blob`, then use `FileReader()` with `response` from `XMLHttpRequest()` as parameter to `.readAsDataURL()`; see http://plnkr.co/edit/To4uZXL8PUph9qG3azvZ?p=preview or use `response.type`

Comment: See version 2 at plnkr http://plnkr.co/edit/To4uZXL8PUph9qG3azvZ?p=preview, using `XMLHttpRequest()` `.response.type.split("/")[1]` , where `.response` is `Blob` returned from request for image, instead of `FileReader()`

Comment: You were right. My Blob([url]) was not the right blob. I just realize it.

Comment: What is `url`? Were you passing the `img` `src` as `url` to `new Blob([url])`?

Comment: Yes. I made a mistake. Actually I'm going to give up. It seems that It has to be done by XMLHttpRequest(), however the img on the page is from another site, which require Access-Control-Request. What's worse, these JS is running in a application made by my company, I can't just execute any request directly. To make some request, Only the   private function of the application is allowed, and it doesn't support any params or responseType. I can do nothing without XMLHttpRequest().

Comment: Try using `canvas` element, `FileReader()` approach; see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32880641/canvascontext2d-drawimage-issue-onload-and-cors

Comment: Sorry. The <img> isn't handled by me. I can't change the <img>. And without XMLHttpRequest() to read the img, I can't do anything.

Comment: I tried canvas, and I got 'Cross-Origin Resource Sharing policy' and 'Uncaught DOMException: Failed to execute 'toDataURL' on 'HTMLCanvasElement': Tainted canvases may not be exported.(…)'. I give up.

Comment: Did you try at the same domain? Try using `fetch` to retrieve the `Content-Type` header

Comment: Another option would be to try using YQL

Answer (score 1):

You can use `XMLHttpRequest()` with `.responseType` set to `"blob"` to request image file; `blob.type.split("/")[1]` where `type` is `MIME` type of `Blob`, `[1]` after `.split()` would be `jpg`, `jpeg`, `png` or other image type

```
  window.onload = function() {
    var aLink = document.querySelector("a");
    var fileName = "image";
    var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
    request.responseType = "blob";
    request.open("GET", "http://example.com/d4eb8d");
    request.onload = function() {
    var blob = this.response;
      var type = blob.type.split("/")[1];
      console.log(type);
      var evt = document.createEvent("HTMLEvents");
      evt.initEvent("click", false, false);
      aLink.download = fileName + "." + type;
      aLink.href = URL.createObjectURL(blob); 
      aLink.dispatchEvent(evt);
    }
    request.send()
  }
```

plnkr http://plnkr.co/edit/To4uZXL8PUph9qG3azvZ?p=preview

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that `new Blob([url])` will return blob with image content? not a text file with this content `http://192.168.1.100/Image_tmp/2016-06/d4eb8d`?

As i know you can turn image link to blob only by read this with XHR => [How to get a file or blob from an object URL?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11901662/5138198)

then when you will have blob, get file type from blob.type. And attach extension

```
var ext ="";
switch(blob.type){
   case "image/jpeg":
        ext=".jpg";
        break;
   case "image/png":
        ext=".png";
        break;
   case "image/gif":
        ext=".gif";
        break;
}
aLink.download = fileName + ext;
```

Comment: OK, you are right. Finally some one could help me correcting my mistake.

Answer (score 0):

You have an instance of [HTMLImageElement](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLImageElement) and, as far as I can tell from the documentation, it doesn't have any property with the image type.

You could grab the URL, launch an AJAX call and get the `Content-Type` header, from which it should be easy to figure out a file extension... assuming the remote server provides the information (if it doesn't, you have a different problem). The [XMLHttpRequest](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest) object has a [.getResponseHeader()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/getResponseHeader) method.

You algo have the poor-man's solution of changing `window.location` to the picture URL but of course there's no way to force a download.

Last but not least, you can build a little server-side script that downloads the file on the server and prepares all the details.