# Base64 convert from image not getting base64 string

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, base64

I am convertin image to base64 string using following code

```
  function getBase64Image() {
    p = document.getElementById("fileUpload").value;
    img1.setAttribute('src', p);
    canvas.width = img1.width;
    canvas.height = img1.height;
    var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
    ctx.drawImage(img1, 0, 0);
    var dataURL = canvas.toDataURL("image/jpg");

    $("#b64").val(dataURL);
}
```

But what I am getting in dataURL is `Data;` and there is not base64 string contained.

How can I fetch base64 string from image?

Comment: You have to read the image first!!

Comment: @Pradeep how to do it?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [CanvasContext2D drawImage() issue \[onload and CORS\]](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32880641/canvascontext2d-drawimage-issue-onload-and-cors)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i think this could work if you use load callback because the loading is async. not sure what your fileUpload is tho, but if's a text field pasting a url

```
function getBase64Image() {
    p = document.getElementById("fileUpload").value;
    img1.setAttribute('src', p);
    img1.setAttribute('load', fileLoaded);  
    function fileLoaded(e) {
      canvas.width = img1.width;
      canvas.height = img1.height;
      var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
      ctx.drawImage(img1, 0, 0);
      var dataURL = canvas.toDataURL("image/jpeg");
      $("#b64").val(dataURL);
    }
}
```

the image type is also image/jpeg. jpg won't work or, it will return png instead since it isn't valid. and cross-origin can be a problem iirc.

Comment: Never use `setAttribute` to attach an event listener. In some cases, you can use its `onload` property, but the best way is to use `Element.addEventListener` method. Using `setAttribute` will set the attribute to the result of `handler.toString()`, you will loose all scoped variables, and I'm not even sure the event will fire...

Answer (score 0):

Here's a simple example:

```
// assuming that you have jQuery lib

$('#fileUpload').on('change', function(e) {
  if (this.files.length === 0) return;

  var imageFile = this.files[0];
  var reader = new FileReader();

    // when reading of image file completes
  reader.onloadend = function() {
    var tempImg = new Image();
    tempImg.src = reader.result;

        // when image is loaded
    tempImg.onload = function() {
      canvas.getContext("2d").drawImage(tempImg, 0, 0);
    }

  }

  // start reading
  reader.readAsDataURL(imageFile);
});
```

Hope this helps!!