# Why does my canvas code produce live results from Chrome's debugging console, but acts inert in regular code?

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I am working on a straightforward double buffering application with HTML5 canvas. (I've commented out the IIFE beginning and end to make debugging easier.) So far as I can tell, when I enter commands live from the developer console, it gives textbook appropriate results for e.g. painting a background image, or scaling and then painting a background image.

I was originally trying to do this as one detail of a tabbed page, but then pulled it out to its own page, which is self-sufficient other than CDN pulls and an uninteresting background image. The code, which duplicates the earlier reported behavior, runs:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>A Snowfall of Skills</title>
        <style type="text/css">
            canvas#display-background
                {
                display: none;
                }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <canvas id="display-background"></canvas>
        <canvas id="display-foreground"></canvas>
        <script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.js">
        </script>
        <script
        src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.0/jquery-ui.js">
        </script>
        <script>
            /*
            ;(jQuery.ready(function()
                {
                */
                console.log('Reached A');
                var original_background_width = jQuery('#display-background'
                  )[0].width;
                var original_background_height =
                  jQuery('#display-background')[0].height;
                var background_width = jQuery(window).width() * .8 - 20;
                var background_height = (original_background_height *
                  background_width / original_background_width);
                jQuery('#display-background')[0].width = background_width;
                jQuery('#display-background')[0].height = background_height;
                jQuery('#display-foreground')[0].width = background_width;
                jQuery('#display-foreground')[0].height = background_height;
                var raw_background = new Image();
                raw_background.src = '/images/skills-snowfall.jpg';
                var background_scale = (.8 * jQuery(window).width() /
                  background_width);
                var canvas_height = background_width / background_scale;
                var background_canvas = jQuery('#display-background')[0];
                var background_context = background_canvas.getContext('2d');
                var foreground_canvas = jQuery('#display-foreground')[0];
                var foreground_context = foreground_canvas.getContext('2d');
                /*
                background_context.drawImage(raw_background, 0, 0);
                foreground_context.drawImage(raw_background, 0, 0);
                */
                background_context.drawImage(raw_background,
                  0, 0, raw_background.width, raw_background.height,
                  0, 0, background_canvas.width, background_canvas.height);
                foreground_context.drawImage(raw_background,
                  0, 0, raw_background.width, raw_background.height,
                  0, 0, foreground_canvas.width, foreground_canvas.height);
                console.log('Reached Z');
                /*
                }()));
                */
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

The page does appear to be working in one thing; the background canvas is meant not to be directly displayed, although it should be copied to the foreground canvas; and Inspecting HTML elements confirms that there is one displayed canvas, with dimensions making sense.

If I reference `raw_background`, Chrome shows an IMG element. If I comment out the bracketing, both scaled and unscaled background declarations work correctly when entered manually to the Chrome console. But the context seems to be a noop when it's run live on the page; the `Reached A` and `Reached Z` messages are displayed with other diagnostics that are not in my code but appear to me to be innocuous.

What, exactly, am I doing that things basically work dead simple when I enter commands in Chrome's console, but show no visible effect when run as regular JavaScript inlined on a page?

Comment: because you have to wait for your img has loaded before being able to draw it on the canvas.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [CanvasContext2D drawImage() issue \[onload and CORS\]](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32880641/canvascontext2d-drawimage-issue-onload-and-cors)