# html canvas problems with context.drawImage()

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, drawimage

I'm using canvas and i'm trying to draw an image to the canvas but it doesn't work. I found that I need to use eventListener but it didn't fix it. can someone tell me what's wrong.

```
const c = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
const ctx = c.getContext("2d");

const groundImg = new Image();
groundImg.src = "ground.png";

groundImg.addEventListener("load", startDraw());

function startDraw() {
    ctx.drawImage(groundImg, 0, 0, c.width, c.height);
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [CanvasContext2D drawImage() issue \[onload and CORS\]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32880641/canvascontext2d-drawimage-issue-onload-and-cors)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

change:

```
groundImg.addEventListener("load", startDraw());
```

to:

```
groundImg.addEventListener("load", startDraw);
```